# In what order does ld-linux.so search shared libraries?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries

When ld-linux resolves a symbol it searches through the shared libraries in a particular order and stops when it finds a shared library with a matching symbol.

What determines the order it searches through the libraries? Does it make a difference if the unresolved symbol is in the main program or in another shared library?

How could I determine the search order programatically without calling external programs like ldd?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/ELF.txt (as mentioned by sarnold):

> When resolving symbolic references,
>   the dynamic linker examines the symbol
>   tables with a breadth-first search.
>   That is, it first looks at the symbol
>   table of the executable program
>   itself, then at the symbol tables of
>   the DT_NEEDED entries (in order), then
>   at the second level DT_NEEDED entries,
>   and so on.

Answer (score 3):

This book http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html suggests left-to-right order as given on the `gcc` command line. (I learned long ago to always place `-lm` as the very last library in a list of libraries to link with, but I've also long since forgotten the cargo-cult reason for that.)

**EDIT**

Aha, thanks for the update. You're going to need to parse the ELF yourself; look for "Shared Object Dependencies" and "DT_RPATH" in http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/ELF.txt. (I also recommend http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html, but it's less applicable to your problem -- just fun reading.)

`/usr/include/linux/elf.h` has all the typedefs.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to work with arbitrary programs, even if I don't know the link line the program was compiled with.

Answer (score -1):

actually the link order can be deduced by using ldd;
if library1 is in linker command line before library2 then ldd will display library1 before library2

Now based on this i wrote a short python script that shows the shared libraries in link order - it does a breadth first search over all dependencies displayed by ldd (for a given executable.

Here is the script

EDIT: note that the script uses ldd, still might be usefull ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import sys
import re

visited_so = {}
ssplit = re.compile('\S+')
verbose = 0

def run_ldd( sopath ):
        ret = []

        pop = subprocess.Popen( [ 'ldd', sopath ], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
        [out, err] = pop.communicate()

        for l in out.splitlines():
            toks = ssplit.findall( l )
            if len(toks) > 3:
                ret.append( toks[2] )
        return ret

def load_order_bfs( pqueue ):
    while len(pqueue) != 0:
        nextexe = pqueue.pop(0)
        if verbose:
            print 'visit ' + nextexe

        if not nextexe in visited_so:
            print nextexe
            visited_so[ nextexe ] = 1

            dependents = run_ldd( nextexe )
            for sopath in dependents:
                    if not sopath in visited_so:
                        if verbose:
                            print '\tnext ' + sopath
                        pqueue.append( sopath )

if len( sys.argv ) == 1:
    print sys.argv[0] + """ <path>
shows dependents of executable in symbol search order;
does a breadth first search over the dependents of the executable
"""
    sys.exit(1)

load_order_bfs( [ sys.argv[1] ] )
```

Comment: The question says "without calling external programs like ldd". Your program calls an external program, namely ldd.